# sort by date with aggregate request in mongodb

Tags: mongodb, aggregation-framework

I would like to retrieve a list of values ​​that comes from the oldest document currently signed.But i failed to select a document absed on the date.Thanks

here is json :

```
    "ad" : "noc3",
    "createdDate" : ISODate(),
    "list" : [
            {
                    "id" : "p45",
                    "value" : 21,

            },
            {
                    "id" : "p6",
                    "value" : 20,             
            },
            {
                   "id" : "4578",     
                    "value" : 319
            }
   ]
```

and here my aggregate request :

```
db.friends.aggregate({$match:{advertiser:"noc3", {$sort:{timestamps:-1},{$limit:1} }},{$unwind:"$list"},{$project:{_id: "$list.id", value:{$add:[0]}}});
```

Answer (score 27, accepted):

Your aggregate query is incorrect. You add the sort and limit to the match, but that's now how you do that. You use different pipeline operators:

```
db.friends.aggregate( [
    { $match: { advertiser: "noc3" } }, 
    { $sort: { createdDate: -1 } },
    { $limit: 1 },
```

Your other pipeline operators are bit strange too, and your code vs query mismatches on `timestamps` vs `createdDate`. If you add the expected output, I can update the answer to include the last bits of the query too.